# Handling transitive dependencies of non-OSGI dependencies in JBoss Fuse

Tags: java, fuseesb, jbossfuse, fabric8

I am using JBoss Fuse 6.2 with Fabric. I have an application that is compiled into an OSGI bundle. The application has a dependency on a non-OSGI jar file (multiplier.jar) and this has a transitive dependency on another non-OSGI jar file (adder.jar).

The application bundle and the two dependencies are all located in the local Maven repository.

I define a features.xml file that looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="CamelLogRepo" xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.0">
  <feature name="multiplier-logger">
    <bundle>mvn:org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse/beginner-camel-log/6.2.0.redhat-133</bundle>
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.acme.math.multiply/multiplier/1.0</bundle>
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.acme.math.add/adder/1.0</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```

I then run these commands in the Fuse console:

```
fabric:profile-create --parent feature-camel logger-profile
fabric:profile-edit --repository file:C:/Tools/jboss-fuse-6.2.0.redhat-133/quickstarts/beginner/camel-log/features.xml logger-profile
fabric:profile-edit --feature multiplier-logger logger-profile
fabric:container-create-child --profile logger-profile root logger
```

This works.

However, I will have to list all transitive dependencies in the features.xml file. Is there any way to avoid this?

I was of the impression that Fuse could do Maven dependency lookup, so if a dependency had a pom.xml in the repository listing another dependency Fuse would load that dependency automatically. Is there any way to achieve this and make Fuse automatically use the `wrap:` protocol for non-OSGI dependencies?

The full test application with the two dependencies can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm1kcctvnwlvb2d/transitive2.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

No you have to list all the dependencies, welcome to OSGi land.

We attempted to add the ease of Maven to OSGi with something called *FAB* [1] - Fuse Application Bundles. But the two worlds are just too different. So in OSGi land you are unfortunately better off having to list all the dependencies in the features files.

- [1] http://www.davsclaus.com/2012/08/osgi-deployment-made-easy-with-fab.html

Comment: And FAB packaging is deprecated as per Fuse version 6.2, right?
Will there be better support for this with version 6.2.1 that will be based on JBoss EAP?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you can also add the dependencies through the Hawtio GUI provided by Fuse/Fuse-Fabric, which would be time-saving compared to using the karaf console for handling profiles and their features/features repositories since you can avoid typos while selecting from the list of available features.

Procedure on the Fuse Management Console (Hawtio) would be as follows:

Having Fabric up and running, go to `host:8181/hawtio` and create the profile as follows if not already done:

*Fabric perspective --> Wiki --> Create --> Fabric8 Profile*

On the profile details screen, you can easily add the parents or dependency features required, as well as feature repositories and artifact deployments, on which maven compiled artifacts and wrapped artifacts can be added. If errors occur, then most likely they'll indicate missing features dependencies on the console logs of that server/container.

Hope this helps someone